# Boot into ubuntu live session from USB

Tags: dual-boot, usb

I am trying setup a dual boot system.

- I already installed windows 8 professional
- I disabled fast boot
- Secure boot state is not supported
- UEFI boot is disabled

In the boot menu my ubuntu-USB drive is listed as a bootable device. But when I select it,the windows 8 starts rather than ubuntu live session. I also tried booting from windows8-bootable-USB (by selecting it in boot menu), it works fine ( I am led to fresh installation of windows).

I am using universal usb installer to create bootable pen drive for ubuntu. How can I get into live session of ubuntu using pen drive and continue installation? Or is there any alternative to setup a dual boot system?

Comment: First of all you shouldn't disable UEFI boot unless you had Windows installed in Legacy mode. All factory installed Windows 8 or newer are in UEFI mode. For dual boot you need to boot the installer drive using the same mode, i.e., how it boots is how it installs. And if you're doing it from Windows, prefer Rufus (as recommended in Ubuntu's official documents) and select the installation type accordingly: GPT/UEFI (for UEFI) or MBR... (for Legacy).

Comment: You should also check with *md5sum*, that the download was good. See this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes. You can use the program *md5summer* in Windows, http://www.md5summer.org/

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the pendrive. Not all pendrives can be used for creating bootable pen drives. Earlier I was using Toshiba 4 Gb pen drive. Later when I used SanDisk 16 Gb pen drive, the problem was solved. Refer to this link for more information: https://www.pendrivelinux.com/recommended-usb-flash-drives/